# Why does 'Func<IBase>' compile while 'Func<TGeneric> where TGeneric : IBase' doesn't?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, delegates, generic-programming

Why is the following bloc wrong?

```
    public interface IBase { }
    public class ClassX : IBase
    {
    }

    public class ClassY
    {
        public static ClassX FunctionReturnX() { return new ClassX(); }
    }

    public class ClassZ<TGeneric> where TGeneric : IBase
    {
        Func<IBase> funcInterface = ClassY.FunctionReturnX; //Right

        Func<TGeneric> funcGeneric = ClassY.FunctionReturnX; //Wrong
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, you cannot cast `ClassX` to any class that implement `IBase`. You are only guaranteed to be able to cast it to `IBase` itself. Consider this example:

Imagine that you have a class `ClassA` that implements `IBase` like this:

```
public class ClassA : IBase
{

}
```

Now, `ClassZ<ClassA>` would look like this (this is not real code):

```
public class ClassZ<ClassA>
{
    Func<IBase> funcInterface = ClassY.FunctionReturnX; //Right

    Func<ClassA> funcGeneric = ClassY.FunctionReturnX; //Wrong
}
```

`ClassY.FunctionReturnX` returns `ClassX` which you can cast to `IBase`, but you cannot cast it to `ClassA`. Therefore, you get the complication error.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ClassX` is definitely a `IBase`, but it might not be `TGeneric` since something else might implement `IBase` and be used for `TGeneric`.